Error installing Visual Studio GitHub Copilot extension for Visual Studio 2022 17.10?
When installing the GitHub Copilot extension for Visual Studio from the marketplace I get the error message that there are no applicable products are available.


There error occurs because the extension requires Visual Studio before 17.10. Starting with the 17.10 update (blog) to Visual Studio 2022 GitHub Copilot is a Visual Studio component and must be installed by the Visual Studio Installer. The component is recommended and will be installed by default.
Installing the extensions from the Visual Studio Marketplace will result in the error above as they are not compatible with the latest Visual Studio version.
If you are using Visual Studio versions earlier than 17.10 they should install fine and upon updating to 17.10 they will be disabled, and the component installed.
To install GitHub Copilot from the Visual Studio installer:

Search for Visual Studio Installer in the start menu

For the installation of Visual Studio you want to add GitHub Copilot to select “Modify”

Got to the Individual Components tab and search for “GitHub Copilot” and check it

Check the checkbox and press modify to start the installation, which will require elevation.

This operation will need elevation.
You can also install it from the command line using the component id Component.VisualStudio.GitHub.Copilot.
Modify an existing Visual Studio install:
<Path to the VS installer (setup.exe)> modify –installPath <Path to the VS instance to modify>
# For example:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe" modify --installPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise" --add  Component.VisualStudio.GitHub.Copilot

You can also add the component to a .vsconfig file. That file can then be used to configure a VS install either from the command line or if checked into a repo anyone opening that repo without the component will be prompted to install it.
{
  "version": "1.0", 
  "components": [ 
    " Component.VisualStudio.GitHub.Copilot"
    ] 
}

